# Searching for a ZipCode website - results only on second click

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geocoding

I created a HTML page for searching for 2 Zip-codes and creating a route between them.

I used: 
Google Map + Direction - for displaying the route on map and like a GPS
GeoCoding - used for getting location from Zip-code

The problem: When I click the "GO!" button for the first time, my variables are undefined, the second time it works OK.

Where could be the problem in my code?

thanks advanced,
Steve

the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Displaying Text Directions With setPanel()</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
      #right-panel {
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }

      #right-panel select, #right-panel input {
        font-size: 15px;
      }

      #right-panel select {
        width: 100%;
      }

      #right-panel i {
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      #right-panel {
        height: 100%;
        float: right;
        width: 390px;
        overflow: auto;
      }
      #map {
        margin-right: 400px;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        background: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: Arial;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.4);
        display: none;
      }
      @media print {
        #map {
          height: 500px;
          margin: 0;
        }
        #right-panel {
          float: none;
          width: auto;
        }
      }
    </style>
  <!--async defer-->
    <script 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initMap()">
    <div id="floating-panel">
 <form onsubmit="codeAddress(); return false" action="#">
      <strong>Start:</strong>
   <input id="start" size="30" type="text" value="403503" />
      <br>
      <strong>End:</strong>
   <input id="end" size="30" type="text" value="788003" />
   <input type="submit" value="GO!">
   <input type="button" onclick="clear()" value="Clear markers" />
 </form>
    </div>
    <div id="right-panel"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
 var map;
 var directionsDisplay;
 var directionsService;
 var firstAddress;
 var secondAddress;
 var geocoder;
 
      function initMap() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 7,
          center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

        var control = document.getElementById('floating-panel');
        control.style.display = 'block';
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(control);
  
  /*geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();*/
        /*var onChangeHandler = function() {
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        };
        document.getElementById('searchBtn').addEventListener('click', onChangeHandler);*/
       // document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
      }

   function clear()
   {
  map.clearOverlays();
  firstAddress="";
     secondAddress="";
   }
      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        var start = firstAddress;
        var end = secondAddress;
  alert('Start:' + firstAddress + ' End: '+secondAddress);
        directionsService.route({
          origin: start,
          destination: end,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }

    function codeAddress() {
        var zip1 = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var zip2 = document.getElementById('end').value;
  /*firstAddress="";
     secondAddress="";*/
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zip1}, function(results1, status1) {
          if (status1 == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            /*map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            if(marker)
              marker.setMap(null);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                draggable: true
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
              document.getElementById('lat').value = marker.getPosition().lat();
              document.getElementById('lng').value = marker.getPosition().lng();
            });
            document.getElementById('lat').value = marker.getPosition().lat();
            document.getElementById('lng').value = marker.getPosition().lng();*/
   firstAddress=results1[0].geometry.location;
   alert();
          } else {
            alert('Geocode Zipcode 1 was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zip2}, function(results2, status2) {
          if (status2 == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            /*map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            if(marker)
              marker.setMap(null);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                draggable: true
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
              document.getElementById('lat').value = marker.getPosition().lat();
              document.getElementById('lng').value = marker.getPosition().lng();
            });
            document.getElementById('lat').value = marker.getPosition().lat();
            document.getElementById('lng').value = marker.getPosition().lng();*/
   secondAddress=results2[0].geometry.location;
          } else {
            alert('Geocode Zipcode 2 was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
  
  /*directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

        var control = document.getElementById('floating-panel');
        control.style.display = 'block';
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(control);*/
  
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
      }
    </script>
 <!--async defer-->
    <!--<script 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `.geocode()` API is **asynchronous**. Your code needs to wait for it to complete.

Comment: should I add a setTimeout or how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function codeAddress() {
        var zip1 = document.getElementById('start').value;
        var zip2 = document.getElementById('end').value;

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var promise1 = new Promise(function(res, rej){
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zip1}, function(results1, status1) {
          if (status1 == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            resolve(results1[0].geometry.location);
          } else {
            reject('Geocode Zipcode 1 was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });

    });
        var promise2 = new Promise(function(res, rej){
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zip2}, function(results2, status2) {
          if (status2 == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            secondAddress=results2[0].geometry.location;
          } else {
            alert('Geocode Zipcode 2 was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(values = {
   firstAddress = values[0];
secondAddress = values[1];
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
})
      }
```

Just hoping that the google apis always respond to your code calls. This will call your last function after response is available from both calls

Comment: It seems that is working OK thanks very much for your code, it helped me a lot